# Why mblen() always returns 1?

Tags: c, unicode

Consider following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAX 64

void main(void)
{
    char napis[] = "coś żółtego";
    int i;
    wchar_t bufor[MAX];
    int ret;

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    printf("zwykły string [%s] długość %d\n", napis, mblen(napis, MAX)); // <---

    ret = mbstowcs(bufor, napis, sizeof bufor);
    if (ret == MAX)
        bufor[MAX-1] = '\0';
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        printf("16 bitowy string: [%ls] długość napisu %d długość %d\n", bufor, mblen(napis, MAX), ret);
        for(i = 0; i < ret; i++)
            printf("%lc|", bufor[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When the code with `gcc -o file file.c` and run it, I always get 1 from `mblen()`. Why does it happen?

Everything else works perfectly, but `mblen()` does not.

I've tried to use LC_ALL, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first `"c"` in `"coś żółtego"` is only 1 byte

> the mblen() function inspects at most n bytes of the multibyte string
>   starting at s and extracts the **next complete multibyte character**.

Change to "żoś żółtego" and see what happens.

Comment: i get mblen()=2 ;-)

Comment: Yes, you get 2, in other words: `mblen` doesn't return the length of the string but the length of the first multibyte character.

Comment: it's still giving me 1 with żoś żółtego

Comment: @user97662 are you calling  `mblen(NULL, 0);` to reset the internal state as stated in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mblen)?